# Wildfly 8.2 : session attributes disapear, when using mod cluster

Tags: wildfly-8, failover, infinispan, httpsession, session-replication

we're using wildfly 8.2 in cluster mode , with ha profil, so as to benefit from failover fonctionnality.

But seems that things don't work properly since we enable `</distributable>` in our web.xml, because session attributes disapear from user's session abnormally.

Here is our cache configuration in domain.xml:

```
    <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                        <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                            <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                        </local-cache>
                        <distributed-cache name="dist" batching="true" mode="ASYNC" owners="2" l1-lifespan="0">
                            <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED" striping="false" acquire-timeout="30000" concurrency-level="20000"/>
                            <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC"/>
                            <file-store/>
                        </distributed-cache>
  </cache-container>
```

Is someone facing the same problem?
is this problem caused by session passivation ?

Comment: Are your site your server nodes have formed a cluster? Are you sure your session values are serializable?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for replay. 
yes, our servers are well clustred, we have 3 nodes and a master in our domain, w've already tested the the failover and it workes without problem, means that our session attributes are serializable.
Our probleme is that in a certan moment, some session attributes disapear from session without a reason, causing a lot of nullPointerExceptions.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it's a bug? I'd suggest upgrading to latest Wildfly version and trying with that.